# How to get ondemand ids for Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo-api

I am trying to work with the Vimeo API and I cannot figure out how to access the ondemand data.

The endpoint and parameters in the [docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/on-demand#get_vod) require an `ondemand_id` to work correctly. I assumed this ID would come from any official ondemand page within Vimeo. But whenever I search the ondemand pages of Vimeo and click on a resource, the URL does not contain any numerical ID.

It only contains the root path for the Vimeo website with `/ondemand_page_name` at the end. This value cannot be the ID since it is a string and not a number. I have looked through the entire page plenty of different times to try to find the ID but cannot seem to find it.

For example, when you visit a normal video page on Vimeo, the URL looks something like this:

`https://vimeo.com/272976101`

where the number 272976101 is the video_id that can be used within the API to get all the data about this particular video. Instead of this format, the ondemand pages have the format:

`https://vimeo.com/ondemand/nebula`

where there is no numerical ID within the URL. This is the issue I am having. How would I retrieve the public data about this ondemand page throught the API.

I feel like there may be a very simple solution/explanation to this issue and any help would be much appreciated.

Also, right now I am not using any SDK to access this data. I am strictly trying to figure out how the API works through the built-in client provided within the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undocumented, but you can use the On Demand custom url path as the `ondemand_id`.

So for your On Demand video at `https://vimeo.com/ondemand/nebula`, you can make an API request to this path: `https://api.vimeo.com/ondemand/pages/nebula`.

In the response, you'll see the `"uri"` value `"/ondemand/pages/203314"`, which you can log on your end and use as the `ondemand_id` instead of `/nebula`.

Also note, this should be the same URL as your On Demand settings page: `https://vimeo.com/ondemand/203314/settings`

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! This definitely helped!